# WhatsApp on Android 11: getting rid of all notifications except for receiving messages?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I have recently installed WhatsApp on a new phone with Android 11. For some reason, WhatsApp keeps bothering me with tons and tons of notifications. 'Backing up' or 'Checking new messages' or 'WhatsApp Web is active' and whatever.

I've never seen this behaviour before on my previous installment (which was on Android 8 or 9) but it's quite annoying.

I can of course disable WhatsApp notifications entirely. However I *do* want to receive notifications in case of actual messages. I just want to disable to other ones.

I've been looking in WhatsApp Settings > Notifications but I can't seem to find any way to do so.

Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Android 8.0, all notifications are assigned to "[channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)". You can access these notification channel settings from Android settings (not the settings within WhatsApp itself) and turn individual channels' notifications on or off. It is up to the developer of the app to decide which notification goes to which channel.

Go to: `Settings -> Apps & notifications`. Select the app in question, then select `Notifications` to access the notification settings.